# Codeigniter pagination links cannot link to a page number

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am a beginner in using Codeigniter pagination. I don't understand what I made wrong with the configuration of the Codeigniter pagination. When I tried to inspect the elements inside of the page number, then I clicked the `href` of my Codeigniter pagination then it successfully works. But when I wrapped it with an `<li>` tag it doesn't link.

Here is my config for the codeigniter pagination:

```
$config = array();
$config['base_url'] = ''.base_url().'hire-workers/';

$config['total_rows'] = $count_all->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 5;    

$config['uri_segment'] = 2;

$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['prev_link'] = ' Previous';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';     

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I tried removing the :

```
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

and my link works but my view was destroyed. I don't really know why, since I am only a beginner in using Codeigniter.

Comment: It looks like it's a styling issue

Comment: @sauhardnc i already figured it out. It is a script issue